# Pagination issue on category.php using custom post type query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I have an issue with pagination on category.php using a custom post type query.

my code :

```
 <section class="products-list">
            <?php

            $current_page   = get_queried_object();
            $category       = $current_page->post_name;          

            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product_elm', 'category_name' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => 2);
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <div class="img">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>   
                    </div>
                    <h2> <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php 
                endwhile;

            }
            next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
            previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </section>
```

When i click on "older entries" i have a "not found" page.

The url seems good though:
/category/chaudieres-a-condensation/page/2/

thank you for your help.

Best Regards